# How to keep keyboard opened after focus other(specific) view in Xamarin.Forms Android / iOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keyboard

I'm working on a project where I have an entry and a button labeled "add", I need to insert Entry.Text into a list view and keep the keyboard opened for more insertions. I found some questions about it but mostly of them are too olds, others simply doesn't have any acceptable answer.

So, is there a way to do that like WhatsApp does when we touch send button?

Comment: you can use the Entry's Focus() method to cause the keyboard to popup, but to keep it open constantly would probably require a custom renderer

Comment: yes... but focus() it's a little bit ugly since it will keep showing/hiding the keyboard. how could be this renderer? do you have any initial idea that I can follow and try to improve ?